# Excel Macro to give Input Box, Create New Sheet, Copy Data from Original Sheet into New Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a Macro that will Present an Input box once a button is clicked, simply saying "What would you like to call the new sheet?", then once the user has entered the name, Excel create a new sheet with that name.

However, I would like for the Data in the Original Sheet to be copied over to the new sheet that has been named by the user.

I have the Input box working, with this code:

```
Sub NewSheet()

Sheets.Add.Name = InputBox("What Would You Like to Call the New Sheet?")    

End Sub
```

Comment: did you try the code below ?

Answer (score 7):

Try the code below:

```
    Sub NewSheet()

    Dim origSht             As Worksheet
    Dim destSht             As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo eHandle

    Set origSht = ActiveSheet

    Sheets.Add.Name = InputBox("What Would You Like to Call the New Sheet?")
    Set destSht = ActiveSheet

    origSht.Cells.Copy Destination:=destSht.Cells

Exit Sub

eHandle:

    MsgBox "You must name the new sheet"
    set origSht = nothing
    set destSht = nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You will also need to trap the cancel button click